# jquery how to wrap every fifth element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know i can do that in the hard way by using for loop or something like that but i'm asking

if :  there is any simple way to wrap every 5 images in a long list of images

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To "wrap" an image with another element:**

Yup, its pretty simple:

```
// document.ready
$(function(){
   $("#yourList img:nth-child(5)").wrap("<div class='image-wrapper'></div>");
});
```

**To force every fifth image onto the next line**

```
// document.ready
$(function(){
   $("#yourList img:nth-child(5)").css('clear','left');
});
```

This could also be done in your CSS, but `nth-child` is not supported across all browsers:

```
#yourList img:nth-child(5){
   clear: left;
}
```

Comment: @CMS... haha, I have to be fast when you are around answering questions :)

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP meant.. seems he's trying to wrap it down to the next line - ie. have only 5 images per line

Comment: @K Prime, you are probably right... i'll update my answer to show both